# What is the problem in use of "send" of web3.js?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I'm trying to use web3.js (v1.0.0) in order to send a transaction to smart contract, so i use `send()` method of the contract. My code:

```js
let contract = new icoWeb3.eth.Contract(getABI(), contractAddress);

contract.methods.myMethod().send({
    from: from,
    value: value
});
```

The problem is that contract.methods.myMethod equals "undefined". So i can't utilize `send()` method to do what i need. Docs example code:

```js
myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]]).send(options[, callback])
```

What do i need to do in order to make method `send()` work? Thanks and i hope for your help...

Comment: You have to pass arguments to the method, don't you? https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id13

Comment: Can you share your contract method please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using send, you are calling a setter method of your contract.

So, you should provide some arguments:

```
 MyMethod(args1 [, args2, ...])
```

Can you provide the method of your solidity contract?